# Angular ,display array using service

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays, angularjs-directive, angular-services

i am learning angular by doing small exercises. i have successfully displayed objects in controller and trying to learn to use service and factory. i am unsuccessful in displaying array "names" on a table using service. please look at my code to see what  i am doing wrong and also how would use factory to display the same array. here is my code

edited question after receiving partial answer:

factory is not not displaying the information ethnicity .

```js
var myApp = angular.module("app",[]);

myApp.filter("agefilter", function(){

var x= function(age){
    if(age==23||age==22){

        return "Young";
    }

    if(age==25){

        return "Mature";
    }
    if(age==26){

        return "Oldest";
    }
}
return x;
});





myApp.controller("ctrl", function($scope,factoryy){

    $scope.person=[

       {name:"jay",age:25,salary:85000},
        {name:"anu",age:23,salary:65000},
         {name:"jose",age:26,salary:75000},
          {name:"sharon",age:22,salary:70000}


    ];
    
//   $scope.callnames = servicee.names(); 
  $scope.calleth   = factoryy.geteth();


});



myApp.factory("factoryy",function(){

     var ethnicity = ["Asian-Indian","Asian-Indian","Chinese","Latino","American"];

     return{

      geteth: function(){

         return ethnicity;
         }
     }

});


// myApp.service("servicee",function(){

//       var names= ["jay","anu","sharon","jose","mary"];
// this.names = function(){
//       return names;
// }


// });
```

```html
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
 <head>
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.8/angular.min.js"></script>
  <title></title>
 </head>
 <body ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl" >
 

 <table border="1">
     <tr>
         <th>Name</th>
         <th>Age</th>
         <th>Salary</th>


     </tr>
  
     <tr ng-repeat="i in person">
         <td>{{i.name |uppercase }}</td>
         <td>{{i.age|agefilter}}</td>
         <td>{{i.salary|currency}}</td>
        

     </tr>



 </table><br><br><br>


  <!--<table border="1">
     <tr><th>Name</th></tr>
  
     <tr ng-repeat="s in callnames">

         <td>{{s}}</td>
    </tr>
    
 </table>-->



  <table border="1">
     <tr>

         <th>Ethnicity</th>
         
     </tr>
  
     <tr ng-repeat="e in calleth">

         <td>{{e}}</td>
    </tr>
    
 </table>



 <script src="../js/angu.js"></script>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: Just a recommendation, but you might find your code easier to debug if you were a little more consistent with indentations and kept your spacing a bit tighter. Keeps things easier to keep track of mentally :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So in order to fix you current implementation you would just need to do 2 things, first update the `servicee.names` in your controller to `servicee.names()` and then in your template update your `s.names` to just `s`

In order to do the same functionality with a factory you would do it this way:

```
myApp.factory("nameFactory",function(){
  var names= ["jay","anu","sharon","jose","mary"];

  return {
      getNames: function(){
        return names;
      }
  }
});
myApp.controller("ctrl", function($scope,nameFactory){
  $scope.person=[
     {name:"jay",age:25,salary:85000},
     {name:"anu",age:23,salary:65000},
     {name:"jose",age:26,salary:75000},
  ];

  $scope.callnames = nameFactory.getNames(); 
});
```

The difference between a factory and a service is that a factory is just a function that is returned so we can return an object that exposes whatever values or functions that we want, while a service is initialized with the `new` operator which allows us to simply expose anything by attaching it to `this`

Comment: thank you. it worked. would you be kind enough to show how would i  implement this in myApp.factory instead of myApp.service

Comment: @AnuRajan I have updated my answer with a factory implementation as well

Comment: can you check what i am doing doing wrong? i think i followed everything you suggested. i edited the code you did to mine

Comment: I dont see any updates/edits to your original answer

Comment: From the edit you suggested I cannot see anything in the actual controller and factory logic that would be causing an issue, you may need to make sure that you have updated your template

Comment: i just updated your answer with my  code with your suggested structure above.

Comment: @AnuRajan your current list of ethnicities has a duplicate in it which will break the ng-repeat, `"Asian-Indian","Asian-Indian",` need to take one out

Answer (score 1):

You must invoke the function of the `servicee` in your controller

```
$scope.callnames = servicee.names();
```

Then in your html,

```
<tr ng-repeat="s in callnames">
     <td>{{s}}</td>
 </tr>
```

EDIT: If you want to use factory instead of service

```
myApp.factory("myFactory",function(){

    var names= ["jay","anu","sharon","jose","mary"];
    this.names = function(){
          return names;
    }

    return this;

});
```

Then in your controller, still the same.

```
myApp.controller("ctrl", function($scope,myFactory){

    $scope.person=[

        {name:"jay",age:25,salary:85000},
        {name:"anu",age:23,salary:65000},
        {name:"jose",age:26,salary:75000},


    ];

  $scope.callnames = myFactory.names(); 


});
```

ANOTHER EDIT: 
    The problem with your array that it has the 2 'Asian-Indian', to fix this you must add track by $index in your html.

```
<tr ng-repeat="e in calleth track by $index">
     <td>{{e}}</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: service work with your structure but factory is not. i have edited the original question . can you check for the error. its not displaying ethnicity table using factory

Answer (score 0):

```js
// var myApp =angular.module("app",[]);

// myApp.controller("ctrl",function($scope){

//  $scope.person =
//  [

//        {name:"john",age:30},
//        {name:"sam",age:20},
//        {name:"jay",age:25}

//     ];
    
//     $scope.title = "Learning Angular"
// })
// _____________________________________________________________________________________
// _____________________________________________________________________________________
// _____________________________________________________________________________________

var myApp = angular.module("app",[]);

myApp.filter("agefilter", function(){

var x= function(age){
    if(age==23){

        return "Young";
    }

    if(age==25){

        return "Mature";
    }
    if(age==26){

        return "Oldest";
    }
}
return x;
});

myApp.controller("ctrl", function($scope,servicee){

    $scope.person=[

       {name:"jay",age:25,salary:85000},
        {name:"anu",age:23,salary:65000},
         {name:"jose",age:26,salary:75000},


    ];
    
  $scope.callnames = servicee.names(); 


});
myApp.service("servicee",function(){

      var names= ["jay","anu","sharon","jose","mary"];
this.names = function(){
      return names;
}


});
```

```html
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
 <head>
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.8/angular.min.js"></script>
  <title></title>
 </head>
 <body ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl" >
 

 <table border="1">
     <tr>
         <th>Name</th>
         <th>Age</th>
         <th>Salary</th>


     </tr>
  
     <tr ng-repeat="i in person">
         <td>{{i.name |uppercase }}</td>
         <td>{{i.age|agefilter}}</td>
         <td>{{i.salary|currency}}</td>
        

     </tr>



 </table> <br><br><br>


  <table border="1">
     <tr>
         <th>Name</th>
         


     </tr>
  
     <tr ng-repeat="s in callnames">
         <td>{{s}}</td>
         
        

     </tr>



 </table>


 <script src="../js/angu.js"></script>
 </body>
 </html>
```